# how to connect reveal menu cell to many view.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I could create reveal menu in xcode and put tableview in it.I create one project that has reveal menu like this :

[image]

Now I want when any cell go to any page but I dont know how to connect top page (white page in picture) to bottom page (menu page that is tableview) that when I click on cell go to next page.

guide me about it. I so confused.

Comment: Now I want when any cell go to any page but I dont know how to connect top page (white page in picture) to bottom page (menu page that is tableview) that when I click on cell go to next page. I couldn't get it please describe it clearly

Comment: my friend I want when to click cell I go to next page but I want white UIView to be different (for example when I to click first cell I go to tableview and when I click second page I go to viewController)

Comment: why you are not using .xib files instead of Storyboard. If i am not wrong

Comment: my friend I like storyboard please tell me about it

Comment: what os different .xib file and storyboard . which is better?

Comment: I always use .xib files to perform any push operation,send an object or anything else. I have more control when using .xib files rather than storyboard

Comment: my friend I dont know about .xib file. I dont know how send an object or push to any page from .xib !!! my friend please tell me

Comment: can you teach me about use .xib in one project???